# Анимация Canvas в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, анимация

Возникла проблема при попытке написать простую анимацию перемещения.

У меня есть два одинаковых изображения, помещенные в `Canvas`. Мне нужно переместить первое изображение, в точности на координаты второго. Вот код:

```
        DoubleAnimation a = new DoubleAnimation();
        a.To = Canvas.GetLeft(img2);;
        img1.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, a);
```

При выполнении данной части кода, возникает следующая ошибка:

```
System.ArgumentException: ""не число" не является допустимым значением для свойства "To"."
```

Как мне получить точные координаты второго изображения, чтобы я их мог вписать в `a.To =`  ?

Comment: А чем вам XAML не угодил? Там намного проще все анимации прописываются, да и канвас для этого особо не нужен, есть же марджины. Канвас больше для рисования подходит.

Comment: 1. Для Марджина все равно нужно знать нужное расстояние.
2. Перемещение будет происходить по ходу программы многократно, из одной точки, в другую. Обе точки будут меняться, по ходу программы. Поэтому XAML мне не подходит.
3. В любом случае, главная проблема в том, как вычислить нужные мне произвольные(в ходе работы программы) координаты второй точки, и использование XAML мне так же не дает ответ, на изначальный вопрос.

Comment: `Обе точки будут меняться, по ходу программы. Поэтому XAML мне не подходит.` между этими двумя предложениями нет никакой связи, а у вас каким-то чудом одно из другого исходит. Познакомьтесь с привязкой данных и конвертерами. В любом случае UI на шарпе в WPF опытные разрабы не пишут, это неэффективно и топорно, поэтому вряд-ли кто подскажет, как вам извлечь присоединенное свойсво зависимости из картинки шарпом и не получить при этом NaN. Учите XAML, факт в том, что ваша проблема там решается, вы просто не знакомы с инструментом. Я бы помог, но задачу вы не озвучили и данных показали мало.

Comment: Покажите, как кладете картинки в канвас, и в чем смысл программируемого эффекта, покажите релевантную разметку и код, что-нибудь придумаем.